# Can anyone explain this C# code snippet to me?

Tags: c#

I saw this in Twitter and couldn't find an explanation that I could understand. I tested this and found that the answer is 1. Thanks in advance.

```
(var @_, var _) = (5,2);
Console.WriteLine(@_/_);
```

Comment: Very sneaky. The answer is 1 because it's calculating `5 / 5` -- in the first statement `_` is a [discard](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/csharp/fundamentals/functional/discards), but in the second statement `_` is not (and `@_` and `_` are effectively the same identifier there, with `@` normally being used to escape keywords). It's effectively the same as `(var a, var _) = (5, 2); Console.WriteLine(a / a)` minus the obfuscation. You would not, of course, hope to encounter such code in production.

Comment: @JeroenMostert Maybe make that an answer

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As pointed out in the comments by [@Jeroen Mostert](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4137916/jeroen-mostert), `_` is a [discard](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/fundamentals/functional/discards), so if you try to name a variable `_`, it would just mean a placeholder name. However, you can escape that and use `_` as an actual name using the `@` symbol, which in C# usually means escape or raw form.

Essentially, `var @_` would mean a variable named `_` while `var _` would mean a placeholder variable, that doesn't have a name and is not addressable.

Now when accessing the variable named `_`, you don't have to do the escape sequence again, `_/_` would be validly accessing that variable. It would be equal to `a/a` if your variable was named `a` instead. But the question has written the code that way to confuse you. Note that the `@` doesn't change anything since `_` isn't considered a discard in the first place. It wouldn't mean anything to "read/access" a discard.

Since `_` is equal to 5, `5/5 = 1`

Comment: Almost -- note that the second statement can also validly be written as `Console.WriteLine(_ / _)` because `_` cannot be a discard in this expression. It's only written as `@_` again to confuse the reader about what's going on. Only the first instance of `_` must be escaped to prevent it from being considered as a discard and bring `_` into scope as an identifier.

Comment: @JeroenMostert Yes, that's right. Thanks for pointing it out. Also, since this is originally your answer and you still seem to be active on the post, you can post your own if you want and I can delete mine.

Comment: That's fine, I don't need my virtual internet points that badly. To the people who actually write answers go the spoils.

Comment: @JeroenMostert Yeah I don't care about the reps either, just thought you've clicked away from the post and wanted to make sure the answer is there. Then I felt bad lol